# Focus keyboard input in chat windows when in champion selection

Tags: league-of-legends

What is hotkey to focus keyboard input in chat windows when in champion selection screen?[image]

Comment: As best I'm aware there is no hotkey for that.

Comment: @AverageUnknown is right, I've wanted one for a while, but there isn't a hotkey for that. I wish man, would take a lot of stress out of trying to call a lane.

Comment: @TrapHappy The new champ select they're testing should make that a lot less important.

Comment: You mean selecting lane when select champion too? Where would I see what they are testing?

Comment: @NamGVU It's on the PBE currently, might even be live soon.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no hotkey for that, however, you can hover your mouse over the location of the text input line as you click accept.